# Inyección sql en consulta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Nunca me había preocupado por el tema de la sql injection (como todo principiante supongo) hasta que ayer vi un video al respecto, incluso inyecté un pequeño sitio que había desplegado en un hosting con los procesos que en dicho video vi.
Entonces he investigado sobre las consultas preparadas ya sea el modo procedural o el orientado a objetos en mysqli o PDO, sin embargo, tengo el siguiente bloque de código que ya me ejecutaba un proceso exitoso, pero ahora con el miedo a las inyecciones no sé si es seguro y como apenas estoy viendo lo de consultas preparadas y demás no sé como modificarlo para que siga funcionando y que a la vez no sea vulnerable en el caso de que lo sea. Aquí mi código:

```
<?php
include('./admin/conn.php');
$fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');
$sql_fechas = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM fechas_universidad WHERE ('$fecha_actual' BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin) AND periodo='$periodo' AND año='$año' AND tipo='Inscripción'");
$row_fechas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_fechas);

$irregular = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT calificacion FROM  calificaciones WHERE calificacion_matricula = '{$user['s_access']}' AND calificacion < 8.0");
$row_irregular = mysqli_fetch_assoc($irregular);

$datos_alumno = "SELECT alumnos.matricula, alumnos.grupo, alumnos.nivel, alumnos.turno, alumnos.cuatrimestre, alumnos.id_carrera, grupos.grupo_actual, grupos.grupo_siguiente FROM alumnos 
INNER JOIN grupos ON alumnos.grupo = grupos.grupo_actual WHERE alumnos.matricula = '{$user['s_access']}'";
$result_alumno = $conn->query($datos_alumno); 
$row_alumno = mysqli_fetch_array($result_alumno);


$cuatrimestre_sig = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row_alumno["cuatrimestre"] + 1,ENT_QUOTES)));  
//$cuatrimestre_sig = $row_alumno["cuatrimestre"] + 1;    
$turno   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row_alumno["turno"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$cuatrimestre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row_alumno["cuatrimestre"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$carrera = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row_alumno["id_carrera"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$grupo_sig = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row_alumno["grupo_siguiente"],ENT_QUOTES)));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM materias WHERE cuatrimestre = '$cuatrimestre_sig' AND carrera = '$carrera' AND turno = '$turno'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



$e_docente = "INSERT INTO  encuesta_docente (matricula_encuesta,estatus_realizo,periodo,año) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','0','$periodo','$año')";
$e_tutorias = "INSERT INTO  encuesta_servicios (matricula_encuesta,estatus_realizo,periodo,año) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','0','$periodo','$año')";
$e_servicios = "INSERT INTO  encuesta_tutorias (matricula_encuesta,estatus_realizo,periodo,año) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','0','$periodo','$año')";
$update_reinscripcion = "UPDATE inscripcion_reingreso SET  inscrito='1'  WHERE matricula_alumno='{$user['s_access']}' AND periodo = '$periodo' AND año = '$año'"; 



if(($turno == "E") && ($cuatrimestre <= "5") && (!empty($row_fechas)) && (empty ($row_irregular['calificacion']))){
    $update = "UPDATE alumnos SET  grupo='$grupo_sig', nivel='TSU', cuatrimestre='$cuatrimestre_sig', periodo_curso = '$periodo', año_curso = '$año' WHERE matricula='{$user['s_access']}'";
    $conn->query($update);
    $conn->query($e_docente);
    $conn->query($e_tutorias);
    $conn->query($e_servicios);
    $conn->query($update_reinscripcion); 
    $index = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $materias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
    $insert_materias= "INSERT INTO alumnos_materias (`matricula_alumno`,`idmat`,`periodo`,`año`) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','$materias','$periodo','$año')";
    $conn->query($insert_materias);
    $index++;
     }
    
}
    elseif(($turno == "E") && ($cuatrimestre >= "6") && ($cuatrimestre <= "10") && (!empty($row_fechas)) && (empty ($row_irregular['calificacion'])) ){
    $update1 ="UPDATE alumnos SET  grupo='$grupo_sig', nivel='ING', cuatrimestre='$cuatrimestre_sig', periodo_curso = '$periodo', año_curso = '$año' WHERE matricula='{$user['s_access']}'";
    $conn->query($update1);
    $conn->query($e_docente);
    $conn->query($e_tutorias);
    $conn->query($e_servicios);
    $conn->query($update_reinscripcion); 
    $index = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $materias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
    $insert_materias= "INSERT INTO alumnos_materias (`matricula_alumno`,`idmat`,`periodo`,`año`) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','$materias','$periodo','$año')";
    $conn->query($insert_materias);
    $index++;
     }
    
}
    elseif(($turno == "D") && ($cuatrimestre <= "8") && (!empty($row_fechas)) && (empty ($row_irregular['calificacion'])) ){
    $update2 ="UPDATE alumnos SET  grupo='$grupo_sig', nivel='TSU', cuatrimestre='$cuatrimestre_sig', periodo_curso = '$periodo', año_curso = '$año'  WHERE matricula='{$user['s_access']}'";
    $conn->query($update2);
    $conn->query($e_docente);
    $conn->query($e_tutorias);
    $conn->query($e_servicios);
    $conn->query($update_reinscripcion); 
    $index = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $materias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
    $insert_materias= "INSERT INTO alumnos_materias (`matricula_alumno`,`idmat`,`periodo`,`año`) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','$materias','$periodo','$año')";
    $conn->query($insert_materias);
    $index++;
     }
    
}
    elseif(($turno == "D") && ($cuatrimestre >= "9") && ($cuatrimestre <= "13") && (!empty($row_fechas)) && (empty ($row_irregular['calificacion'])) ){
    $update3 ="UPDATE alumnos SET  grupo='$grupo_sig', nivel='ING', cuatrimestre='$cuatrimestre_sig', periodo_curso = '$periodo', año_curso = '$año'  WHERE matricula='{$user['s_access']}'";
    $conn->query($update3);
    $conn->query($e_docente);
    $conn->query($e_tutorias);
    $conn->query($e_servicios);
    $conn->query($update_reinscripcion);
    $index = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $materias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
    $insert_materias= "INSERT INTO alumnos_materias (`matricula_alumno`,`idmat`,`periodo`,`año`) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','$materias','$periodo','$año')";
    $conn->query($insert_materias);
    $index++;
     }
    
}
    elseif(($turno == "V") && ($cuatrimestre <= "8") && (!empty($row_fechas)) && (empty ($row_irregular['calificacion'])) ){
    $update4 ="UPDATE alumnos SET  grupo='$grupo_sig', nivel='TSU', cuatrimestre='$cuatrimestre_sig', periodo_curso = '$periodo', año_curso = '$año'  WHERE matricula='{$user['s_access']}'";
    $conn->query($update4);
    $conn->query($e_docente);
    $conn->query($e_tutorias);
    $conn->query($e_servicios);
    $conn->query($update_reinscripcion); 
    $index = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $materias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
    $insert_materias= "INSERT INTO alumnos_materias (`matricula_alumno`,`idmat`,`periodo`,`año`) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','$materias','$periodo','$año')";
    $conn->query($insert_materias);
    $index++;
     }
    
}
    elseif(($turno == "V") && ($cuatrimestre >= "9") && ($cuatrimestre <= "13") && (!empty($row_fechas)) && (empty ($row_irregular['calificacion'])) ){
    $update5 ="UPDATE alumnos SET  grupo='$grupo_sig', nivel='ING', cuatrimestre='$cuatrimestre_sig', periodo_curso = '$periodo', año_curso = '$año'  WHERE matricula='{$user['s_access']}'";
    $conn->query($update5);
    $conn->query($e_docente);
    $conn->query($e_tutorias);
    $conn->query($e_servicios);
    $conn->query($update_reinscripcion); 
    $index = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $materias = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($row["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
    //$materias = $row["id"];
    $insert_materias= "INSERT INTO alumnos_materias (`matricula_alumno`,`idmat`,`periodo`,`año`) VALUES ('{$user['s_access']}','$materias','$periodo','$año')";
    $conn->query($insert_materias);
    $index++;
     }
    
}
else{
    echo"<script>alert('Ha ocurrido un error al inscribirte, comunícate al departamento de control escolar.')</script>";
}


 
if ($insert_materias == TRUE) {
    header("Location: /SIGE/Dashboard");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert_materias . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Este proceso se ejecuta en el action de un input type submit. Pero después de lo que vi en el video ya no sé si es seguro, si alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo seguro y sugerencias para prevenir las inyecciones, agradezco de antemano su colaboración.

Comment: No es seguro. El primer paso es sanitizar las variables que te entran (esa parte no la pusiste en tu código), por ejemplo si tu esperas un número verificar que es número, o si es un texto que sea alfanumérico (siempre que fuera posible), esto también te ayuda a la inyección de script que es otro tema de seguridad.   El resto puede leerlo acá https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/301324 que está muy bien explicado

Comment: Las variables que recibo no provienen de inputs si es a lo que te refieres, la mayoría son campos que traigo en los SELECT y los vacío en arreglos, antes de publicar la pregunta tenía certeza de que no debía estar seguro, donde me estoy complicando es como transformar mi query a una consulta parametrizada y que tenga el mismo resultado que ya logré pero con la seguridad de prevenir inyecciones. Es un tema complejo porque no entiendo como alguien podría inyectar código si el proceso lo hace un botón y no es a través de un GET en la url o a través de un input text o situaciones parecidas

Comment: Un select puedes editarlo desde el navegador, presionas F12 y cambias el value de un option y puedes enviar lo que sea, puedes cambiarlo desde JS con la consola. Pero es irrelevante, porque los ataques no se hacen manualmente, se hacen con herramientas, así que da lo mismo que tu tengas un boton, un imput o un select, lo importante es lo que recibes en el servidor y como lo procesas

Comment: Si el atacante sabe leer el código (o la herramienta de hackeo que use) podrá ver el destino (action o ajax) de la petición, reconociendo el nombre y ruta del script destino de la petición,y los datos que se esperan enviar (los name en un formulario tradicional o bien leyendo el ajax que haga la petición). A partir de ahí puede elaborar un script de shell para realizar las peticiones simulando ser un navegador que viene de la misma página y enviando los datos esperados pero modificados para encontrar tus vulnerabilidades SQL u otras, y usando fuerza bruta con listas de cadenas inyectables

Comment: @Yussef no hay que abusar de la sanitización. Por ejemplo, si los datos no se van a imprimir no hace falta sanearlos. En cuanto a seguridad con respecto a *inyección SQL*, preferiría **consultas preparadas reales**, en vez de `mysqli_real_escape_string`, por dos motivos: 1) sobre `escape_string` pesa un pasado sombrío (en la versión anterior se podía inyectar código aun con cadenas escapadas); 2) las consultas preparadas son más seguras y más rápidas, porque el SGBD, ante una consulta preparada traza un plan de ejecución y las consultas sub-siguientes serán más rápidas.

Comment: Entiendo `<?php
$matricula = $user['s_access']; 
$datos_alumnos = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE matricula = :matricula";
$objetoPDOStat = $pdo->prepare($datos_alumnos);
$objetoPDOStat->bindParam(':matricula', $matricula, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$exito = $objetoPDOStat->execute();


while( $row = $objetoPDOStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    $grupo = $row['grupo'];
}` Segun me he documentado, ¿se supone que esta consulta ya es segura?

Comment: Y esta es mi conexión   `<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=sige;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
$usr = 'root';
$pwd = '';

$options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
);

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $errMsg='SERVER ERROR!';
    echo $errMsg;
    error_log($errMsg);
       
}
?>`

Comment: @DEATH_FENIX99 Sí, ahora la consulta ya es segura contra inyección SQL, lo has hecho bien (si te funciona, claro, sino algo mal tendrás, pero la idea es esa)